# Direction of Stack Reference

Tags: assembly, kernel, intel

[Here is a bit of kernel code](https://github.com/Andromeda-OS/Kernel/blob/master/osfmk/x86_64/idt64.s#L506-L508) that may be incorrect. My question is this:

1. The `add` instruction on line 506 "deallocates" a structure on the stack by moving the stack pointer back past it. (`ISS64_OFFSET` is the size of the structure; the extra 24 bytes were `push`ed separately, but are still considered part of the structure.)
2. However, line 508 then retrieves part of the buffer from #1. (`ISF64_CS` is an offset into the structure; and I have to account for those extra 24 bytes as well.) Would I need to negate the offset (i.e. do `-ISF64_CS-24`) in order for it to pick up the correct data?
3. If I would need to negate the code in #2, would I also need to alter [lines 522–524](https://github.com/Andromeda-OS/Kernel/blob/master/osfmk/x86_64/idt64.s#L522-L524) the same way?

Comment: It looks like it is trying to read from the *next* structure on the stack, not the one just deallocated.  This assumes that `ISF64_CS` is something larger than 24, and that these structures are pushed back to back on the stack.

Comment: **If** the address before line 506 was `ISF64_CS(%rsp)` (can't see proof of that) then after line 506 you just have to undo the addition, so the correct address would be `ISF64_CS-ISS64_OFFSET-24(%rsp)`. You do not need to negate the member offset, since the order of the fields hasn't changed, you have just moved the base address.